# Is it possible to track how long a user is in a voice channel?

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make a Discord statistics bot, based on Statbot.
One of its features is tracking how long users have been in voice channels.

I checked the docs for `VoiceState` (which is retrieved from the `voiceStateUpdate` event), and there seems to be no built-in property for how long the user has been in a channel.

How would I do the same?

(Edit: I'm hoping for a solution where I don't have to save every time someone joins/leaves)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check how long have you user been in voice channel you need to know when you user join room and when user left room and store the time user join somewhere base on your favor So the code will be

```js
bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', async (oldState, newState) => {
  let newUserChannel = newState.channel;
  let oldUserChannel = oldState.channel;
  if (oldUserChannel === null && newUserChannel !== null) {
      // User Join a voice channel
      // Handle your save when user join in memcache, database , ...
    } else if (oldUserChannel !== null && newUserChannel === null) {
      // User Leave a voice channel
      // Calculate with previous save time to get in voice time
    } else if (
      oldUserChannel !== null &&
      newUserChannel !== null &&
      oldUserChannel.id != newUserChannel.id
    ) {
      // User Switch a voice channel
      // This is bonus if you want to do something futhermore
   }
});
```

Comment: Nice! However, I was looking for a solution that doesn't need to save the join/leave dates.   I will use this if nobody else's answers satisfy the above criteria. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You have to do it this seem the only way now. Mark it solution if it help. There maybe some library support this that will write base on this way